# how do i exclude more that one directory in this case ... find ./dir1 -name '.git' -prune

Tags: macos, find

How do I exclude more that one directory in this case:

```
find ./dir1 -name '.git' -prune
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `-o` (or):

```
find . '(' -name a -o -name b ')' -prune -o -print
```